# How to host over HTTPS with nodejs using an existing certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I bought a certificate for HTTPS SSL connection on a hosting website. I received a [name].crt file

```
var options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./https/8546332154a5224.crt')
};
var app = express();
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var expressWs = expressWs(app, server);
```

I believe I need a Certificate Signing Request File .csr and a private key. I don't know how to generate them.

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: @Ryan I am on Linux

Comment: *"I bought a certificate for HTTPS SSL connection on a hosting website. I received a [name].crt file"* - If you've bought a certificate than you would need to have a CSR and a matching key in the first place - and this is the key you need to use here. I think you need to remember what you actually did when you bought the certificate and follow the instructions you likely received.

Comment: To be clear, you normally need the CSR to get a cert from a CA, but not afterwards. To run a server, you need the privatekey, server cert, and the appropriate _chain_ (aka intermediate) cert(s) for the CA. To run a _nodejs_ server you need those three things in OpenSSL-compatible PEM format or PKCS12 (aka PFX) format. OP: please look at your files and identify what you actually have and whether it matches this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenSSL from the command line. OpenSSL generates the private key and CSR files:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr
```

Comment: I believe that the server and signed certificate are not valid. I get
_tls_common.js:135
      c.context.setCert(cert);
                ^

Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line